# Convert Object[] to specific type

Tags: c#, linq, windows-phone-8

I am developing a Windows phone application which makes use of a `LongListSelector` . I have a `**IList**` declared which would contain items of a the LongListSelector.

`public IList SelectedItems = new List<Object>();`

`SelectedItems` would contain the items selected/removed from the UI of the LongListSelector  in the Selection changed event as shown below.

`SelectedItems.Add(e.AddedItems); 
SelectedItems.Remove(e.AddedItems);`

I want to **cast SelectedItems to my specific model** which i am currently doing as below.

`AwaitingJobs` being a list of my model.

`List<AwaitingPickingJobModel> AwaitingJobs = new List<AwaitingPickingJobModel>();`

```
dynamic selectedItemsObject = SelectedItems.OfType<Object>().ToList();
foreach (var items in selectedItemsObject )
{
    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        AwaitingPickingJobModel awaitingModel= item;
        AwaitingJobs.Add(awaitingModel);
    }
}
```

Is there any way the above logic could be done in a more efficient/better way using linq or any other way possible ?

Comment: have a look at the Select transform.. Or even SelectMany

Comment: @daveL : Thanks for the help . But unfortunately Select transforms cannot be applied to IList .

Comment: It sure doesn't... But to use the Select transform extension you need to include the System.Linq namespace

Answer (score 3):

(Do you really mean that you want to cast the objects? Or is your collection declared as containing `object`s but actually contains the type that you need? )

If the former, then possibly you are looking for the [`Enumerable.Cast` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which will convert any `IEnumerable`'s elements to a given class:

```
var awaitingJobs = SelectedItems.Cast<AwaitingPickingJobModel>();
```

For the latter, or if your source list might contain multiple different types, then `OfType` method could be your solution, and returns a strongly-typed collection:

```
var awaitingJobs = SelectedItems.OfType<AwaitingPickingJobModel>();
```

(I'm not sure why you've used the `OfType` method in your posted code, as the `dynamic` in your code is basically redundant.)

Comment: Thank you for the reply mate .
My declared collection is of type object. But i would like to cast it to my own object . The line you suggested
`var awaitingJobs = selectedItemsObject.Cast<AwaitingPickingJobModel>(); ` gives an exception message as below
`"'System.Collections.Generic.List<object>' does not contain a definition for 'Cast'"`
`Exception source : "Anonymously Hosted DynamicMethods Assembly" string`
The same applies for the second line suggested .
`Exception Message :"'System.Collections.Generic.List<object>' does not contain a definition for 'OfType'"`

Comment: You will need to include `using System.Linq` at the top of your file, and include the appropriate reference (to System.Core.dll). But also, you should remove the `dynamic` since this will be confusing things - just call those methods on `SelectedItems` directly (I'll edit to clarify that).

Comment: Also, regarding casts: you collection is *declared* as type `object`, but the items *in* your collection are *not* `object`s. Assuming they're already your model type, you could use the second option.

Comment: I did try again with the corrected answer, but the collection `var awaitingJobs` is always null .
Only `SelectedItems.OfType<Object>()` is returning me a value .